# Creating a 3-level tree structure from a flat list of objects

Tags: c#, list, data-structures, hierarchy

I have a list of objects like this:

```
1001
Name
Type
Country
```

To display these results in a browser, I need a structure that is something like this:

```
Country1
    Type1
        Name1
        Name2
    Type2
        Name3
Country2
    Type3
        Name4
    Type4
```

I currently have a `List<CustomObject>()` which is ordered by country, then type, then name.

I have tried several solutions involving way too many `foreach` loops, with the latest attempt involving new `County` and `Type` objects that can both have `Children()` to try and make up the structure. However, the process of adding to each of these the correct items within the nested loops simply isn't producing a complete list of any use. I can get to the point of having multiple lists (of `County` and `Type` objects), but then combining these with the correct relationships isn't proving straight forward.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

- You can use a `JSON` object to store a tree structure.
- You can have something like this:
  `class typeObject : Dictionary<String, List<String>>{}`
  `class countryObject : Dictionary<String, List<typeObject>>{}`
  Your data then could be stored as `List<countryObject>`